# Problem calling an API that requires a key in header, using JS and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, key

Since I want to display the result of an API call in a HTML page, I used Ajax in a Javascript to get the information from the API.

The DEV API does not require a key, and I have been able to get the result (yeah!)

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "https://api-dev.XXXXXXXXX.com/enterprise/123456/treeCount/2020-05",
            async: false,
            success: function(result){
                totalCount = totalCount + result.count;
            }
        }),
```

So this code above works fine.

The Prod API requires a key in the header though, and I can't make it work. Found lots of example in StackOverflow, but all my tests failed.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.XXXXXXXXX.com/enterprise/123456/treeCount/2019-12",
            headers: { "x-api-key" : "12345678910" },               
            async: false,
            success: function(result){
                totalCount = totalCount + result.count;
            }
        })
```

It works well in Postman when adding x-api-key with the value of the key, so I know that the key is good

[image: Key in Postman]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT February 15th:**
Thanks for your answers. Went in the console, saw some CORS error, and then I added some information related to CORS and to Content-Type, so my new code in the JavaScript is the following:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.XXXXXXXXXX.com/enterprise/123456/treeCount/2019-12",
            headers: { "x-api-key" : "12345678910",
                   "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },             
            async: false,
            success: function(result){
                totalCount = totalCount + result.count;
            }
        })
```

Still get the same error message though:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>   jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.XXXXXXXXX.com/enterprise/123456/treeCount/2020-05' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

When In only do the call on the Dev API (who does not require an API key), it works fine as indicated above, and I do not get the CORS error.

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: what error are you getting in api response ?

Comment: looks good,  can you confirm in the browser network inspector that the header is being sent?

Comment: try setting the `contentType: "application/json"` in the request, that's the only thing i see is different from the postman request

Comment: as  izambl mentioned, add 'contentType' and also check if there is any error in console - Press F12  to see console.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it helped me narrow the problem. New details added in the description.